# Interactive HTML Form Using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

How can I make interactive HTML form, example :

```
<select name="command">
    <option value="send">Send</option>
    <option value="cancel">Cancel</option>
</select>

<!-- 
    I want the following text input hidden by default,
    but active only if option "Cancel" is selected
-->
<input type="text" name="cancel_reason" id="needreason">
```

I want the "cancel_reason" input field is hidden by default, and shown if dropdown-option "Cancel" is selected before, otherwise it should remain hidden.

Comment: well @meouw just googling around.. tried some 'onChange' event based on #id.. but still not working.. still working around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vxgxg/3/). Non jQuery

```
<select id="command" name="command" onchange="javascript:selectChanged()">
    <option value="send">Send</option>
    <option value="cancel">Cancel</option>
</select>

<!-- 
    I want the following text input hidden by default,
    but active only if option "Cancel" is selected
-->
<input type="text" id="needreason" name="cancel_reason" style="display:none">

<script>
    function selectChanged()
    {
        if (document.getElementById('command').value == "cancel")
            document.getElementById('needreason').style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById('needreason').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your answer here. Add a fiddle if you like, but don't force me to go there

Comment: just great @xbonez except for double id's there.. i changed one of the 'id' to 'name' and adjust the 'getElementById' to the latest 'id'.. works like a charm.. thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
$('select[name=command]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'cancel')
    {
       $('#needreason').show();
    }
    else
    {
       $('#needreason').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript function

```
function show_text_box(value)
{
  if(value=='cancel')
  {
    $('#needreason').show();
  }
  else
  {
    $('#needreason').hide();
  }
}
```

Call this function on your select at `onchange` event

```
<select name="command" onchange="show_text_box(this.value);">
```

and set text box hide

```
<input style="display:none;" type="text" name="cancel_reason" id="needreason">
```